Docker containers with distinct IPs connecting to localhost process via TCP - docker network setup
I'm not sure if what I'm trying to do is impossible. I've seen that containers on an ipvlan network can't ping underlying host interfaces due to a Linux security feature, but I don't know enough about networking to know if that is relevant here or if there's a workaround.
I have a Docker instance that tries to establish a TCP connection. My goal is to start up several of these containers in a Linux environment where each will maintain its own separate TCP connection to a central process running on a separate host. My current development setup has everything on the same host due to hardware limitation, but eventually the target host will be a separate physical host, at which point this should (?) be a lot easier.
To clarify, when NOT running in a container, a single instance of my app establishes a TCP connection to localhost on port 12345. I want to be able to containerise the app and run it on an ipvlan network such that each container has a separate IP address, with the external process listening and accepting connections from each.
The containers themselves are running Ubuntu and my central process is running on Windows. I'm launching them through docker on WSL2 but its integrated with Docker Desktop, if that makes any difference.
My Docker network setup:
docker network create -d ipvlan --subnet 192.168.200.0/24 --gateway 192.168.200.254 -o parent=eth0 -o ipvlan_mode=l2 mynetwork

Running my Docker container like this:
docker run --network=mynetwork mytest:latest

where internally it connects to 192.168.200.254 on port 12345.
This returns No route to host.
I tried adding -p 12345:12345 but that didn't do anything. I know that WSL can connect to localhost because before I containerised this, I could run the app connecting to 127.0.0.1:12345 and it worked fine, localhost forwarding is set up. If I try 127.0.0.1 in the container it returns Connection refused, but that is expected, I think.
I tried adding --aux-address 'host=192.168.200.253' and have the container connect to that but it still showed No route to host.
I tried running the docker container with --network=host forgoing the ipvlan stuff, I saw a couple of new interfaces in ifconfig from within the container but all of those addresses got Connection refused.
Same results on --network=bridge just without the extra interfaces appearing.
I tried playing around with ip addr and ip link but I'm starting to feel drowned by too many things going on I don't properly understand - feels like these experiments are going nowhere.
Before I keep barking up the wrong tree, is it even possible to set it up the way I'm going for?
I'm sorry if my question doesn't make any sense, I'm really a beginner to networking and terms like subnet and gateway confuse me a lot still at this point. If you know any resources that could help shed light on what I'm trying to do that would be extremely helpful too.
